# Android парсинг Html страницы

Tags: android, jsoup

Здравствуйте. Есть рабочий код парсинга страницы. Дебажил на андроиде 5.1 - все норм. А на 4.4.2 - не хочет считывать документ. Использовал библиотеку Jsoup. Может будут какие- нибудь предложения??

UPD:

```
myLink = "http://horo.qip.ru/names/%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(myLink).get();
String s = doc.text();
Elements div_text = doc.select("div.descr");     
 results = div_text.text();
```

Comment: Есть предложение пройтись дебаггером, ну или показать стек-трейс, если имеется. Или объяснить, в чем выражается Ваше «не хочет считывать документ».

Comment: @post_zeew, в документ не забираются все классы(только первые 5 div-ов), хотя на 5.1 весь код страницы забирает и парсин. А стек-трейс я не покажу, т.к. сомо подключение проходит норм и исключений нету.

Comment: Ну тогда самое первое предложение весьма актуально.

Comment: @post_zeew, да сюда не писал , если б перед этим дебагером не проходился несколько раз.

Comment: а чем именно являются ваши "андроид 5.1", и "4.4.2"?

Comment: @metalurgus, версии андроид.

Comment: на "версии андроид" запустить приложение невозможно. Его можно запустить на устройстве, работающем под управлением ОС Андроид, либо на эмуляторе такого устройства. Так вот, чем именно являются те сущьности, на которых вы запускаете?

Comment: @metalurgus OC Android, т.е. реальное устройство.

Comment: Какое именно? Господи, на каких конкретно устройствах вы пробуете?

Comment: @metalurgus lenovo a2010 и huaweu y560 соответственно